# show array data in table using ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, zend-framework

I am using Zend Framework to implement the website. For example I have an array `$shadow` contain somes ID of people. The `$shadow` query is executed in Model and call out in Controller without problems. Now I want to show the data in a HTML table in View using Ajax because of some issues, i can not use PHP to do it. Can anyone show me how to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have table like this in view :

**Html View**

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Phone No</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**jQuery Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
   url : 'url_path_of_controller',
   type : 'POST',
   datatype : 'JSON',
   success : function(data){
       // here we populate data returned by controller
       // if returned data is a plain array, then parse into javascript obj
       var d = $.parseJSON(data);
       // d = [{ name : 'john', phone : 123 }]; --> example
       // this depend on your returned data from controller
       var output;
       $.each(d,function(i,e) {
          // here you structured the code depend on the table of yours
           output += '<tr><td>'+e.name+'</td><td>'+e.phone+'</td></tr>';
       });

       // after finish creating html structure, append the output
       // into the table
       $('#myTable').append(output);
   }
});
```

**Controller**

```
function bla(){
  $shadow = call_from_model
  echo json_encode($shadow);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/metallurgical/ahtroL6j/)** => without ajax request